# MQTT broker destroy execution hangs at Paho library : iOS

Tags: ios, mqtt

I have an application which works as a `MQTT` client. Broker initialization and topic subscription is working fine. When we lock the phone, the connection will disconnect. After that when user loads the app from background `MQTTAsync_destroy(&client)` will execute. Then the execution stops with a

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code =1).

Comment: using MQTT pho library. what other information needed?

Comment: didn't understand your question. Sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MQTTAsync_destroy(&mqttClient);` this was causing the problem. The mqttClient was not correctly passed to the function. The solution is:

```
HomeViewController* strongSelf = (__bridge __weak HomeViewController*)context;
    MQTTAsync mqttClient = strongSelf.mqttClient;
```